# Define a variable and an equation for the situation - Why Division and not multiplocation equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Dwight wants to buy a camera that is on sale for 25% off. The original price of the camera is $300. What is the amount of the discount?
Define a variable, write an equation and solve algebraically.

**The expected solution is a division equation**

**Why is a multiplication equation an incorrect solution ?**
**Let d = amount of discount;**

**d = 0.25 x 300**

Would greatly appreciate your reply.

Comment: I mean, that's fine too...unless your teacher specifically wanted in the form of some division.

Comment: Nothing wrong with that.  Don't know how to do it by division.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is correct. Any multiplication statement can be rewritten as a division equation:

$$d=0.25 \times 300 = \frac{1}{4}\times 300 = \frac{300}{4}$$